# Problem With Objective-C Categories

Tags: iphone, objective-c, categories

The following code is giving me an error of "Cannot find interface declaration for 'StartTimerViewController'

```
#import "StartTimerViewController.h"

@interface StartTimerViewController (timerMethods) 

-(void)startTimer:(id)sender withTimeIntervalInSeconds:(NSTimeInterval)time 
        andMessage:(NSString *)message
notificationChoice:(BOOL)notificationChoice
      andWithLabel:(UILabel *)theLabel;

-(void)updateLabel:(NSTimer *)timer;

@end
```

Why is this occurring?  StartTimerViewController.h does exist and is a valid class I coded.  This file, is supposed to be a category extending StartTimerViewController.

Here's the beginning of StartTimerViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "StartTimerViewController+timerMethods.h"

@interface StartTimerViewController : UIViewController {
```

Comment: What does your `StartTimerViewController.h` look like? Try a clean and build and see if Xcode finds your class this time around.

Comment: At which file/line is the error reported ? Is it really reported for the `@interface StartTimerViewController (timerMethods)` line ?

Comment: Is StartTimerViewController in the same project as this on and included as a file in the bundle being built for this target?

Comment: No, It's reported for the -(void)startTimer:(id)sender withTimeIntervalInSeconds:(NSTimeInterval)time

Comment: Yes, StartTimerViewController is int he same project as this

Comment: Possibly something to do with importing both files into each other? Like a circular reference?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have a circular reference.  You cannot include timermethods.h inside StartTimerViewController.h because timerMethods.h needs StartTimerViewController.h.  You should never need the parent to know about the Category, only the category needs to be aware of the Parent.

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

You're importing the category's header before the class is declared. It never gets a chance to see the class because it comes first! So move `#import "StartTimerViewController+timerMethods.h"` to the *end* of the file.